# Bluetooth not working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

Since when I got rid of windows 8 and installed ubuntu, my bluetooth never really worked. Ubuntu detects the bluetooth hardware (it shows the bluetooth icon in the status bar), and I can turn it on or off and set the visibility and such. However, it is never able to find any bluetooth device, and when I try to connect to my laptop from an other device, it usully doesn't find my computer. If it does find my computer, it will show it using the name it had in windows (I don't know if it's supposed to do that or not), and connecting to he laptop gives a communication error.

I don't know exactely what's causing the problem, but I know that the bluetooth settings on windows 8 were quite glitched, which caused bluetooth to be always on untill you interrupted a device search, after which it was off untill the next reboot. Because of this, I think that maybe the glitched windows drivers messed something up that ubuntu doesn't repair. 
I did try ubuntu in a virtual machine in windows a few times before fully installing ubuntu, and bluetooth worked fine then.

This laptop has been fully tested in the factory yesterday after an overheating gpu was fixed, and they claim that all hardware behaved as it should. So I don't think it's a hardware issue.

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450348/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 8):

Use `rfkill` to ensure there isn't any hard/soft block on your bluetooth device. Issue:

```
rfkill list
```

If block is there, use the unblock option to unblock it :

```
rfkill unblock wlan1
```

Replace wlan1 with the type for your bluetooth device.

Refer [Here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/rfkill)

Comment: There were no hard/soft blocks in that list.

Comment: Then there seems to be issues in even detection. Can you paste the output of lspci and lsusb ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rdQFvB3G

Comment: Hmmn. Loooks like your bluetooth isn't detected at all. Try a few things: 1-Issue "rfkill list all". The all clause works sometimes. 2-Visit this link and try installing the missing packages as suggested: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286834/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04. 3-If nothing works, you have to file a bug at launchpad.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 beta 1 Bluetooth didn't recognize my headset either. It never finished pairing.

@user308564 answer nearly worked for me. However, `bluez-hcidump` was not available. I only removed it from the package list and *voilà*, pairing worked correctly.

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups \
  bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez \
  bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 \
  python-gobject python-dbus
```

Comment: Install the above on `Mate ubuntu 14.10` has removed the bluetooth icon from display, then oddly installed an 'android' settings menu to left of my screen. Restarted machine and now both bluetooth applet and android settings screen are gone!

Comment: running that apt-get worked for me in 15.04

Comment: Please note that for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it's `libgnome-bluetooth13` rather than `libgnome-bluetooth11` and that several of the listed packages are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with bluetooth on Dell Inspiron 15R.

What's amazing, it works perfectly on Ubuntu 12.04. After fresh installation, I was able to connect any bluetooth device.
After upgrading to 14.04 - there's no such possibility and when I type:

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

I see warning *can't load firmware.*

I suppose that some of the proprietary firmware might be deleted/removed from the latest Ubuntu release. I've tried to install *firmware-linux-nonfree* package and some of mentioned above, but it doesn't help.
I guess that solution might be to find firmware on old Ubuntu machine and copy to the latest release.

Comment: I copied all firmware files from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and Bluetooth works properly:
    cp * /lib/firmware/
    
    as I can see:
    Bluetooth: firmware loaded

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed via  Ubuntu software center.... I had every bluetooth software (blue icon) installed except the manager. 
I just had to install Bluetooth Manager from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing bluetooth driver packages :

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus
```

Comment: It still behaves the same, even after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth device of Ben_g is not supported under any kernel at this time

```
ID 0930:021c Toshiba Corp.
```

If someone needs it to work add a comment with `uname -a` and I can modify the source code for it to work as it is another Atheros AR3012 bluetooth device