# Cannot connect any bluetooth devices

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04, bluetooth

I am unable to connect any bluetooth devices to my machine. Last night I had my bluetooth headphones connected. I disconnected them and tried to connect another bluetooth device. However after spending a while trying to get anything to connect, I was not able to connect any devices anymore.

Now when I scan for bluetooth devices, no unpaired devices show up and I am unable to connect anything. I tried rebooting multiple times and also a software update. I still cannot get it to work. I did temporarily set `disable_ertm` since this is needed to connect one device. However this doesn't persist through restart and I don't think this caused any issues.

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04 (although I just upgraded from 19.10 today).

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
[    3.118373] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.118396] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.118403] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.118406] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.118410] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.142526] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810225019140f34
[    3.142528] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 34
[    5.486384] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.486386] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.486389] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  320.144846] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  320.144851] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  320.144855] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  446.535250] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to disable LE scan: status 0x0c
```

The last line `failed to disable LE scan` happens when I turn off and on bluetooth in the settings.

Here is the output of `systemctl | grep -i blue`

```
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.3-0000:02:00.0-usb1-1\x2d6-1\x2d6:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                                   loaded active     plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0                                            
  bluetooth.service                                                                             loaded active     running   Bluetooth service                                                                
  bluetooth.target                                                                              loaded active     active    Bluetooth
```

Here is the output of `rfkill list all`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Here is the output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:8009 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. USB-HID Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is output of `bluetoothctl`

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 80:32:53:8F:AC:B3 lamoreauxaj [default]
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 8C:C8:CD:87:67:DB DTVBluetooth
Device 5E:13:95:A9:16:76 BT SPEAKER
Device F1:DC:AE:DB:C9:7E MX Master 2S
Device F1:DC:AE:DB:C9:7C MX Master 2S
Device F1:DC:AE:DB:C9:7D MX Master 2S
Device 4C:24:98:5E:63:73 AnnePro2 P1
```

These devices were previously connected, however I am unable to connect to any of them or unpaired devices.

I'm really not sure what may have caused bluetooth to stop working for me. However I would really appreciate any advice. I tried looking into the `failed to disable LE scan` error, and this showed up in issues that occurred in a previous kernel version, but those workarounds didn't fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue. I'm not sure exactly what fixed it, but I was following [another stack overflow post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543821/bluetooth-not-working-properly-not-detecting-devices) which suggested reinstalling bluez after deleting /etc/bluetooth as well as installing linux-firmware.

I did both of these and shutdown and rebooted after a minute. Everything now works. Dmesg no longer shows the `failed to disable LE scan` message either.

Comment: The "failed to disable LE scan" error went away, but bluetooth is still not working.