# Bh-proht headset Ubuntu 14.04LTS Bluetooth Issues- 1/05/2016! Still not working!

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, ubuntu-studio, headset

01/05/2016 Greetings is their anyone out their that can explain why my Bluetooth headset does not work with any ubuntu device using pulse audio..
Still experiencing the same problem.. I have decided to go back to Windows until it can be figured out.. Just using my xubuntu in a virtualized environment since simple things like audio and bluetooth which has been around for a decade is still lacking compatibility across the board..

Having said this i did try a fresh install of Xubuntu 14.04LTS and still was unable to get bluetooth to work with the below information posted here.. Please some one fix this bug!

10/07/2015 still no fix to bluetooth audio devices as of now..

I have found work around but no true fix..
So my question is this what would it take to fix this bluetooth problem??

Here is a list of issues with Bluetooth.

1. When bluetooth device does not work well in Telephony mode.. Sounds like a codec issue or something
2. After synchronizing your device it does not recognize in pulse audio automatically unless you do extra steps to get it to work..
3. If i turn on High Fidelity Playback (A2DP) the audio sounds great but cant use the devices microphone..  Yes the device works well with other devices however the moment i move to linux the device sounds like crap unless I turn on the High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)
4. Use ability when designing an operating system like linux its best that you want to make it as user friendly as possible with out having a ton of extra steps.. Just critiquing everyone's code a little.. I personally dont mind installing things like  qemu virtualization stuff like that that is a breeze compared to dealing with blue tooth issues that are absolutely silly in the fact that it works one day the next day it doesnt..

To give you an idea how much trouble i have had with bluetooth I literally setup qemu virtualization had it up and running no problems with scripts and command line and reading but when i turn to this bluetooth problem their is 1 million results and no real solutions to fix it..

This here is a work around however it is not a solutions!
The script i run to get the audio to work only works about half the time.. I think this problem goes back to faulty coding of some sort.. I am not a guru on building this type of stuff but one would have thought that key features on reloading or refreshing things should have been built into the gui..

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Bluetooth 
Comment=
Exec=/usr/bin/terminator -x sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Icon=
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false

Now I am back to square one bluetooth synchronizes just fine but pulse audio for some reason doesnt detect it.. This happened to me after reboot..
9-10-2015

I event put sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover in rc.local

So... Now what..

Hi I found some other Bluetooth help topics but none of them have addressed my issue I have Xubuntu 14.04LTS Quad core hyperthreaded shows 8 cores with 8 gigs of ram..

1st off I could pair the blue tooth but not hear any audio.
Also i looked in Pulse Audio for the device and their was nothing their that would resemble the Blue tooth device I was connecting..

2nd I always hate posting in forums so.... I decided to do a ton of Googling with nothing really found to help the situation..

I did find this article [Bluetooth not working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490346/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts#)

This article did not seem to help with my issues after installing this list ***Due not Do these commands unless you want a headache***

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups \
  bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez \
  bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 \
  python-gobject python-dbus
```

Could some one please tell me where i messed up and what seems to be the issue that in Windows I can connect up a Bluetooth Headset just fine but the moment I reach Linux bluetooth is like its a second thought..

Thanks in advance for any help with this project getting my bluetooth to work correctly.

Here is the terminal results:

```
pactl list short | grep blue – 

loren@loren-Laptop:~$ pactl list short | grep blue – 
grep: –: No such file or directory
loren@loren-Laptop:~$
```

After fighting with the above command I decided to purge all the mess i installed earlier using this command.

```
sudo apt-get purge bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus
```

This command saved my hide..

Then I ran `sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop`

Now i can control the bluetooth like settings and delete the bluetooth devices however still having issues with getting any audio through pulse audio..

---

```
loren@loren-Laptop:~$ sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover 
Failure: Module initialization failed
loren@loren-Laptop:~$
```

This command did not work but device is paired and connected however still having audio issues..

This is far from a duplicated post due to the fact that it involved so many failed variables from all the other post surrounding bluetooth..

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com/questions/259354/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluetooth-headset

Comment: One problem after running the below commands for some reason I can not access the settings on the devices.. sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups \ bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez \ bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 \ python-gobject python-dbus

Comment: Loren, please edit your question to include terminal results for `pactl list short | grep blue`

Comment: For some odd reason it didn't find anything pretty odd though..

Comment: So is anyone going to fix this issue in future releases of the next stable Ubuntu release????

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` followed by pairing with the device will show it in sound settings.

If you use Blueman for a bluetooth manager, you may need to use the command after every reboot

Comment: loren@loren-Laptop:~$ sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover 
Failure: Module initialization failed
loren@loren-Laptop:~$ 

This command did not work but device is paired and connected however still having audio issues..

Comment: I have given up officially in using Linux with blue tooth products

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was a combination of pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

However this failed on me the first time.. And after reboot.. I am not sure who is responsible for the back end type processes with Bluetooth but some one needs to put this command in every time a device synchronizes..sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

Ok.. After researching and researching and researching here is what i did to make it easier on my self and those who are completely computer retarded (Like my self..) I created a script to fix this issue...

### Bluetooth.sh

## !/bin/sh

sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

The above is only a temp fix to the your Blue tooth nightmares. I am no expert but one would have thought that this command would run automatically during synchronization or at least put some thing on the gui to point to this command..

Warning this might not fix everyone issues their are so many variations of problems with Bluetooth in Ubuntu..

Now to run this command I created a Launcher from the desktop

Their is a couple of ways one can do this..
Here is one method that might be easier..

Right click on Desktop create Launcher.
Name: Bluetooth
Command: /usr/bin/terminator -x sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

Click Save Then double click on the icon and make it Executable

Just remember when you synchronize up a bluetooth headset to run this command..

After installing
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

Keep in mind this is after I removed the above commands that I peformed and also ran sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop

It finally appeared in pulse-audio I am not sure why this was left out in installation..

Thank you all so much for you help and commitment to the Ubuntu project..

Reference to this post that i found useful with the solution.. after searching google with this command: pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

[Pulseaudio not detecting bluetooth headset automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366032/pulseaudio-not-detecting-bluetooth-headset-automatically)

Comment: ok so how about fixing the duplicate to add in the steps i took to create it then.. That is if your really wanting to mark it as a duplicate..

Comment: How do I challenge a moderator on this forum.. I might as well start up my own forum if you guys wont take the time to leave the solutions up for others to learn if they run into the same issue.

Comment: Is their any fix to this problem?

Comment: Remove blueman and use Ubuntu's bluetooth manager and you shouldn't need to use the script anymore, or you could put `sleep 20` above your command in the script to see if the command runs after blueman is loaded

Comment: I have to use the script every time the computer reboots or whenever the bluetooth device gets un-synced from the system..