# Bluetooth on laptop doesnt work. Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth

I'm unable to get my new wireless headset to work with my Ubuntu 15 installed laptop.

I've tried installing what i think are the correct drivers for my WiFi card. I have a hp stream 11.
which has a wifi/bluetooth combined card. which is a model: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n

But when I input the command:

```
$ bluetoothd -d -n
bluetoothd[7094]: Bluetooth daemon 5.35
bluetoothd[7094]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing main.conf
bluetoothd[7094]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DiscoverableTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[7094]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'PairableTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[7094]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'AutoConnectTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[7094]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'Name' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[7094]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'Class' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[7094]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DeviceID' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[7094]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'ReverseServiceDiscovery' in group 'General'
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[7094]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

edit:Also this could be useful

```
 WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 01
   serial: d8:5d:e2:d9:34:a3
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.0.3 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:16 memory:90400000-90407fff
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Install Bluetooth.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jqigkapf383tod/bluetooth-15.04.tar.gz
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgcu075lvvzq690/BCM20702A0-413c-8143.hcd
sudo cp BCM20702A0-413c-8143.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
tar -zxf bluetooth-15.04.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Then check to see if firmware loaded `dmesg | tail` please post this in a comment or edit your question to include

```
echo btusb | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

When your kernel updates, the bluetooth will fail until you

```
cd bluetooth
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD clean
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Source: [Ubuntu 15.04 - Bluetooth - No adapters found - Dell Precision M4800](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614319/ubuntu-15-04-bluetooth-no-adapters-found-dell-precision-m4800/614339#614339)

Comment: ok i tried first time. it worked on setting up. but no device detected. so i reset bios. then try searching for devices again and it tells me in blueman assist "No adapter found"

Comment: ok, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Dont feel bad i have been trying to get blue tooth working in 14.04 LTS with no real answer to why its failing..

Same machine and configuration but with Windows my bluetooth headset works fine with linux i would much rather setup QEMU in place of virtual box then to figure out what goes wrong between pulse audio and the blue tooth...

In fact i did configure set up QEMU easier than my blue tooth night mares..

[Bh-proht headset Ubuntu 14.04LTS Bluetooth Issues- 1/05/2016! Still not working!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671736/bh-proht-headset-ubuntu-14-04lts-bluetooth-issues-1-05-2016-still-not-working)