# Bluetooth not working properly, fix fully broke it

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 15.04 on a dell E7450 and I had successfully paired my phone and wanted to pair some wireless headphones, however it refused to find them (my phone paired with headphones fine).

I attempted a to find a solution and, somewhat in desperation, found this answer:

[Bluetooth not working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490346/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

And tried installing the suggested packages thinking there would be limited harm in doing so.

However, now the bluetooth indicator is entirely missing and when I turn on bluetooth by directly opening the manager, nothing happens  and it still reads 'bluetooth is disabled' on the left hand side.

I tried using the blueman applet, but it reads 'no adapters found' when I try to search for devices.

After installing the packages above the hci0 bluetooth interface was listed as softblocked but I have now unblocked it and `rfkill list` now reads:

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no 
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth 
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Can anyone help?

EDIT: As requested the output to

```
lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
```

is:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1bcf:28ae Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [8086:15a2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:062e]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5410]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
[    7.176619] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.17.12.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.620504] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    8.620521] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.620525] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.620527] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.620531] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.693276] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[    8.705410] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[    8.809356] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[    9.802225] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.802227] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.802231] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.812115] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    9.812122] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    9.812126] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

HOWEVER:

After a restart (not the first [more like the fifth]) the bluetooth icon has decided to return and it is back to its first state of functionality. That is:

My phone will pair with my laptop
My headphones will pair with my phone
BUT My headphones are simply not discovered by my laptop

The headphones in question are blueant pump mini HD's

Is there any reason as to why they aren't even discoverable *only on my laptop which functions normally for other bluetooth devices*

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 went EOL in February. Please stop voting to close.

Comment: Wrong close reason, but if it is EOL and version specific (as it appears to be) then it is now unanswerable so voted no-repro