# Bluetooth cannot find any devices

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I'm very new in Linux. I did installed Ubuntu 16.04 and it did recognized my laptop Bluetooth (appeared on menu bar). but when I try to connect my laptop to other devices neither laptop nor Mobile phones couldn't find each other. I also installed the blueman application but problem stayed.
I also look at some other thread's and saw some terminal code which I mention them below :

```
    lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
    04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6605]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:57b4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04ca:2006 Lite-On Technology Corp. Broadcom BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 1058:0820 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport Ultra (WDBMWV, WDBZFP)
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of these questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/787023/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts http://askubuntu.com/questions/490346/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: non of  them worked for me... also those questions have no answer

Comment: Both questions have many answers.